# Error XLS0414 The type 'ViewModels' was not found. Check that a reference to an assembly is not missing and that all referenced assemblies have been c

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Severity Code Description Project Project File Line Status suppressed
Error XLS0414 The type 'ViewModels' was not found. Check that a reference to an assembly is not missing and that all referenced assemblies have been compiled.  TravelAppSample C:\TravelAppSample-masterTravelAppSampleViewsTravelPage.xaml 8
I get this error I have already checked the folder in the source directory and the file is found in the local location.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TravelAppSample" 
             x:Class="TravelAppSample.Views.TravelPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext >
        <local:ViewModels.TravelViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext >

    <ContentPage.Content> 
        <StackLayout>

            <!-- Principal-->
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f8b732" HeightRequest="350">
                <!-- Main image-->
                <Image Source="PrincipalImage" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
                <!-- Place name & travel date-->
                <Label Margin="30,0,0,0">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                   <Span Text="Cuzco &#10;" FontSize="28" FontAttributes="Bold" ForegroundColor="White" />
                                   <Span Text="20 Marzo - 27 Marzo" FontSize="17" ForegroundColor="White" />
                                </FormattedString>
                     </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label> 
                <Frame CornerRadius="35" Margin="0,0,0,-20" BackgroundColor="#f8b732" HasShadow="False" HeightRequest="25" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Days-->
            <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        HeightRequest="85"  
                        Orientation ="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout x:Name="DaysBlock" 
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Padding="20,15,20,5">
                    </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

          <!-- Schedule-->
          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f8f9fb">
               <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding travelSchedule}"
                               SelectedItems="{Binding commmantest}"
                               VerticalOptions="Start">
                     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>  
                                  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="30,10">

                                      <!-- Time-->
                                      <Label Text="{Binding Time}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"/>

                                      <!-- Travel indicator-->
                                      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"> 
                                        <Image   Source="{Binding TransportType}" HeightRequest="30"/>  
                                        <BoxView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="2" Color="{Binding TransportColor}" HeightRequest="70" Margin="20,0"/>
                                      </StackLayout>

                                      <!-- Place to go-->
                                       <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="90" VerticalOptions="Start" />

                                      <!-- Place description-->
                                       <StackLayout>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Adress1}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Silver"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Adress2}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Silver"/>
                                       </StackLayout>

                               </StackLayout>
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
               </CollectionView>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout> 
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhiUE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhiUE.png)
```

esta es la imagen del error:
[image]

Comment: please do **NOT** post code or errors as images.  What **namespace** is `TravelViewModel` in?  The folder location does not matter, the `namespace` does

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a namespace like this:

```
  xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TravelAppSample.ViewModels"
```

please refer to the `TravelPage.xaml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TravelAppSample.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TravelAppSample.Views.TravelPage>

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:TravelViewModel></viewmodels:TravelViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>



</ContentPage>
```